# How to add placeholder text for a pie chart in plotly Python if all inputs in values field is zero

Tags: python-3.x

I have the following code in plotly :

```
    fig.append_trace(go.Pie(labels=labels_allDevicesPassed,
               values=values_allDevicesPassed,
               showlegend=False,
               textposition='inside',
               hovertemplate=hover_value3,
               domain=dict(x=[0, 1]),
               textinfo='value'), row=2, col=2)

    fig.update_layout(
    font=dict(
        family="monospace",
        size=25,  # Set the font size here
        color="black"
    )
)
    fig.show()
```

The problem is for values_allDevicesPassed I have all values as 0 and therefore I don't see any pie chart formed.

Is there any way we can assign a placeholder(something like "No devices to show") if the input in the values field is all zero?

Thanks.